# How force to rebuilds all block list?

Tags: 6, blocks, caching

When I change some block info, in my custom module, sometimes the block doesn't change in my page, even if I clear all cache.

Is there anything I can do for force change?

Comment: Could it be your browser cache as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the blocks admin page `admin/build/block`, that will fix it 99% of the time. Function in question for the rebuilding task: [_block_rehash()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_rehash/6). Also see [block_flush_caches()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_flush_caches/6).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes clearing the cache twice in a row helps, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing the code of an enabled module, you should disabled it from the modules' page, and then re-enable it. This forces Drupal to clear its cache, which includes also a cache containing the list of hooks implemented by all the modules.

Still better, you should disable the module before editing it, and re-enable it after you edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in page scope via hook_preprocess_page() as following

```
function MODULE-NAME_preprocess_page(&$vars){
         //make changes in the blocks         

         //rebuild the blocks managed via Block module
         block_page_build($vars['page']);
         //rebuild the blocks managed via Context module
         context_page_build($vars['page']);

          //set the new changes in cache
         drupal_set_page_content($vars['page']);
}
```